# Upload image programmatically in user account

Tags: users

I used the below code to upload default picture field. Other than this default picture field, I have another field to upload image (for Example, field name "field_house_image"). How to upload file Programmatically.

```
$tmp_photo_realpath = "images/".$userimgname;
        $tmp_photo = "images/".$userimgname;
          $file = new stdClass();
          $file->uid      = $uid;
          $file->status   = 0; // mark the file as temporary
          $file->filename = basename($tmp_photo_realpath);
          $file->uri      = $tmp_photo;
         // $file->filemime = image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($tmp_photo_realpath));
          $file->filesize = filesize($tmp_photo_realpath);
         $infofile = explode("/",$tmp_photo);   
        $infoext = explode(".",end($infofile));
        $imgext = end($infoext);

      // The file should be an image
      $errors = array();
      $errors += file_validate_is_image($file);
      $errors += file_validate_image_resolution($file, variable_get('user_picture_dimensions', '100x100'));
      $errors += file_validate_size($file, variable_get('user_picture_file_size', '30') * 1024);

      // Make sure file extension is a valid image
      if (!in_array(strtolower($imgext), array('jpg', 'png', 'gif'))) {
        $errors[] = ' invalid image file extension.';
      }

      if (count($errors)) {
        drupal_set_message(t('Profile Image Import:') . ' ' . $errors[0], 'warning');
        // Clean up (set fid to avoid error messages)
        $file->fid = 0; file_delete($file);
      }
      else {
        // We'll need a valid file id on the file object; file_save() will give us one
        $file = file_save($file);
        // Update user account (fid is not empty, status is temporary -- image
        // will be moved to proper directory and assigned to the user)
        $fields['picture'] = $file;
        $account = user_save($account, $fields);
    }
```

---

```
EntityDrupalWrapper Object
(
    [id:protected] => 26679
    [bundle:protected] => 
    [entityInfo:protected] => Array
        (
            [path] => user/%user
            [metatags] => 1
            [label] => User
            [controller class] => UserController
            [base table] => users
            [uri callback] => user_uri
            [label callback] => format_username
            [fieldable] => 1
            [entity keys] => Array
                (
                    [id] => uid
                    [revision] => 
                    [bundle] => 
                )
        [bundles] => Array
            (
                [user] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => User
                        [admin] => Array
                            (
                                [path] => admin/config/people/accounts
                                [access arguments] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => administer users
                                    )

                            )

                        [rdf_mapping] => Array
                            (
                                [rdftype] => Array
                                    (
                                        [0] => sioc:UserAccount
                                    )

                                [name] => Array
                                    (
                                        [predicates] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => foaf:name
                                            )

                                    )

                                [homepage] => Array
                                    (
                                        [predicates] => Array
                                            (
                                                [0] => foaf:page
                                            )

                                        [type] => rel
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )

        [view modes] => Array
            (
                [full] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => Doctor Login
                        [custom settings] => 
                    )

                [token] => Array
                    (
                        [label] => Tokens
                        [custom settings] => 
                    )

            )

        [static cache] => 1
        [field cache] => 1
        [load hook] => user_load
        [translation] => Array
            (
            )

        [schema_fields_sql] => Array
            (
                [base table] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => uid
                        [1] => name
                        [2] => pass
                        [3] => mail
                        [4] => theme
                        [5] => signature
                        [6] => signature_format
                        [7] => created
                        [8] => access
                        [9] => login
                        [10] => status
                        [11] => timezone
                        [12] => language
                        [13] => picture
                        [14] => init
                        [15] => data
                    )

            )

        [token type] => user
        [bundle label] => User
        [xmlsitemap] => Array
            (
                [process callback] => xmlsitemap_user_xmlsitemap_process_user_links
            )

        [plural label] => Users
        [description] => Users who have created accounts on your site.
        [access callback] => entity_metadata_user_access
        [creation callback] => entity_metadata_create_object
        [save callback] => entity_metadata_user_save
        [deletion callback] => user_delete
        [form callback] => entity_metadata_form_user
        [view callback] => entity_metadata_view_single
        [configuration] => 
    )

[propertyInfo:protected] => Array
    (
        [bundles] => Array
            (
                [user] => Array
                    (
                        [properties] => Array
                            (
                                [field_enterprise_blog_firstname] => Array
                                    (
                                        [label] => First Name
                                        [type] => text
                                        [description] => Field "field_enterprise_blog_firstname".
                                        [getter callback] => entity_metadata_field_property_get
                                        [setter callback] => entity_metadata_field_property_set
                                        [access callback] => entity_metadata_field_access_callback
                                        [query callback] => entity_metadata_field_query
                                        [translatable] => 
                                        [field] => 1
                                        [required] => 1
                                    )

                                [field_enterprise_blog_lastname] => Array
                                    (
                                        [label] => Last Name
                                        [type] => text
                                        [description] => Field "field_enterprise_blog_lastname".
                                        [getter callback] => entity_metadata_field_property_get
                                        [setter callback] => entity_metadata_field_property_set
                                        [access callback] => entity_metadata_field_access_callback
                                        [query callback] => entity_metadata_field_query
                                        [translatable] => 
                                        [field] => 1
                                        [required] => 
                                    )

                                [field_enterprise_blog_picture] => Array
                                    (
                                        [label] => Picture
                                        [type] => field_item_image
                                        [description] => Field "field_enterprise_blog_picture".
                                        [getter callback] => entity_metadata_field_verbatim_get
                                        [setter callback] => entity_metadata_field_verbatim_set
                                        [access callback] => entity_metadata_field_access_callback
                                        [translatable] => 
                                        [field] => 1
                                        [required] => 
                                        [auto creation] => entity_metadata_field_file_create_item
                                        [validation callback] => entity_metadata_field_file_validate_item
                                        [property info] => Array
                                            (
                                                [file] => Array
                                                    (
                                                        [type] => file
                                                        [label] => The image file.
                                                        [getter callback] => entity_metadata_field_file_get
                                                        [setter callback] => entity_metadata_field_file_set
                                                        [required] => 1
                                                    )

                                            )

                                    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing that using `entity_metadata_wrapper` since it's the easiest way. You should have [Entity API](https://drupal.org/project/entity) installed to use this function. A working example from one of my projects (I've changed the variables to fit your question):

```
$user_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $uid);

$tmp_photo_realpath = "images/" . $userimgname;
$contents = @file_get_contents($tmp_photo_realpath);
$uri = 'public://images/user/' . $userimgname;

$file = file_save_data($contents, $uri);
$file_info = array(
  'fid' => $file->fid,
  'filename' => $file->filename,
  'filemime' => $file->filemime,
  'uid' => 1,
  'uri' => $file->uri,
  'status' => 1,
  'display' => 1,
);

$user_wrapper->field_house_image->set(array($file_info));
$user_wrapper->save();
```

If your field `field_house_image` is a multi-value field, you can use a loop like (suppose you have an array of multiple images named `$file_infos`):

```
foreach ($file_infos as $key => $file_info) {
  $user_wrapper->field_house_image[$key]->set($file_info);
}
$user_wrapper->save();
```

Comment: I am getting page error in this line :
$user_wrapper->field_enterprise_blog_picture->set($file_info);

Comment: Is the field_enterprise_blog_picture a multi-value field?

Comment: No. It's only one value field. Below ... I 'll send $user_wrapper array.

Comment: Ok, it seems you need to set $key no matter if the field is multi-value or not. I'll update my answer, and please try it with a key.

Comment: I kept key value .. showing this error.
Fatal error: Cannot use object of type EntityStructureWrapper as array in .....test.php on line 354.

Plz once check the edited question, which I have printed $user_wrapper array.

Comment: I've updated my answer again. I've removed the key and wrapped the $file_info in an array in set() function. I also added $user_wrapper->save(), which at first I forgot to add.

Comment: Getting page error. sorry... my question is wrong.. field_enterprise_blog_picture is default picture field of drupal 7, here machine_name was changed, but my above code is not working in this site. In other site it is worked well. $file = file_save($file); is not working here..